# Как сменить origin

Tags: git, smartgit

Ситуация следующая: у меня не было ветки master, я ни разу не коммитился, а затем решил запушить много-много изменений.

Я сделал первый коммит "Initial Commit", а затем создал ветку markup и запушил все изменения. В итоге сейчас на Гитлабе я имею только ветку markup, а ветки master нет вовсе.

К тому же у меня в SmartGit origin стоит на локальную ветку markup.

Могу ли я как-то сделать так, чтобы в моем удаленном репозитории была ветка master с коммитом "Initial commit", а от нее была ветка markup, куда я смогу сливать изменения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

командой *push* можно отправить в отдалённое хранилище только какой-нибудь существующий указатель (мы же помним, что в программе *git* «ветка» — это указатель на коммит). под тем же именем, или под любым другим произвольным.

т.е., чтобы в отдалённом хранилище появился (пока отсутствующий там) указатель на какой-нибудь произвольный коммит, надо предварительно создать локальный указатель на этот самый коммит.

создать локальный указатель `имя`, указывающий на коммит с определённым хэшем, можно, например, командой *checkout* (этот указатель сразу станет и текущим):

```
$ git checkout -b имя хэш
```

а теперь указатель можно отправить в отдалённое хранилище (обозначенное, например, как `origin`) под нужным вам именем — `master`:

```
$ git push origin имя:master
```

---

если локальный указатель `имя` вам после этого не нужен, то можете его удалить, предварительно, конечно, сделав текущим какой-нибудь другой указатель (например, `markup`):

```
$ git checkout markup
$ git branch -d имя
```